# How to divide a number by 2 as many times as possible in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, division

I would like to write a program that reads an integer and then divides it by 2 as many times as possible while writing the number as a product of two numbers multiplied by a number that is no longer divisible by 2.

For example:

I would like an integer: 120

120 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 15

Here is as far as I have gotten (updated based the well-meaning
comments but still not perfect):

```js
let num = Number(prompt('The number: '));

let i = 0;
while(!(num % 2)) { 
    num /= 2; 
    i++; 
}

let solution = Array(i).fill(2).join(' * ');

console.log(solution);
```

Comment: The basic idea would be to keep dividing and checking the modulus `x % 2` each time to see if it's still divisible by 2.

Comment: Rather than *"I would like to write..."* this reads more like you want someone else here to write it. Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. SO isn't a free code writing service

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: sorry, I updated the question with the code I have

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there - you got how to get how many `2` you need - now just need to add the remaining `num` onto it - and maybe remember the total:

```
let solution = Array(i).fill(2).join(' * ') + " * " + num;
```

Full solution:

```js
let num = Number(prompt('The number: '));
let total = num; // remember for later

let i = 0;
while(!(num % 2)) { 
    num /= 2; 
    i++; 
}

let solution = total + " = " + Array(i).fill(2).join(' * ') + " * " + num;

console.log(solution);
```